# Normalize string for index/search

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I want to store a normalized version of a `String` to be able to make `like 'xxxx%'` searches on it.

And I'm looking for a good one which be efficient and friendly with user searches.

My initiall idea is to convert to lowercase, remove non letter characters, accents and redundant blanks but don't know if there is a good one already studied and implemented and ready to go.

PD: The string will contain location names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I ended with a custom solution. It could be more efficient but it's performing well for me:

```
public static normalize(String string) {
    string = string.toLowerCase();
    //Remove/change all special characters -->  àaç is converted to aac

    String temp = Normalizer.normalize(string, Normalizer.Form.NFD);
    string = pattern.matcher(temp).replaceAll("");
    //Remove extra spaces  
    string = StringUtils.normalizeSpace(string);
}
```

The `StringUtils.normalizeSpace` is from [Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/). You can easily [get the code](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/commons/proper/lang/trunk/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.java) from the function if you don't want to introduce the dependency:

```
private static final Pattern WHITESPACE_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("(?: \\s|[\\s&&[^ ]])\\s*");

public static String normalizeSpace(final String str) {
    if (str == null) {
        return null;
    }
    return WHITESPACE_PATTERN.matcher(trim(str)).replaceAll(SPACE);
}
```

Comment: Does it work for all languages? Even Hebrew where the extra signs are actually additional Unicode characters (example: "בְּרֵאשִׁית" should become "בראשית") ? If so, how would you search for text after using it, as there is a different in length of the string between before the normalization and after it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you use the Search API? It provides text normalization by default, and is designed to be used with end-user queries (i.e., you can pass user queries onto the Search API without need for validation, if you use indexes/namespaces correctly).

Comment: No, it's not an option by me because I want to use for autocomplete textbox with near 2M registers and I don't want to incur in exceeded quotas or additional costs